# Modify view to a waiting screen

Tags: android, view

I am working on my first App, and got stuck on some point.
In my MainActivity there is an onClick Method, which is linked
to a button in the main layout file:

```
    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/IncludeAlbum"
    android:text="@string/scan"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    />
```

This is the onClick:

```
    public void onClick(View view){

    view.setVisibility(view.GONE);

    View v1 = (View) findViewById(id.Welcomemessage);
    v1.setVisibility(v1.GONE);

    //
    // ... many more visibility changes
    //

    loaf = new ListOfAudioFiles();  // TAKES TIME

    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(id.listView1);
    adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, allComparisons); //loaf.songinfos

    lv.setAdapter(adapter);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adpterView, View view, int position,
                                long id) {
            ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

            long viewId = view.getId();

            if (viewId == R.id.textView1) {
                allComparisons.get(position).togglecb1();
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            } else {
                allComparisons.get(position).togglecb2();
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

        }
    });

}
```

Not very clean, I know, but I would like to keep the structure. The listofaudiofiles constructor does a lot time consuming stuff.

My problem is that I cannot change the view to some wait screen before calling the listofaudiofiles constructor, neither do (post)invalidates work nor does setContentView on a new layout. Modifying the the view by setText also does not give anything. Only when the list is populated all the view changes appear.

How can I achieve view changes in onClick(...) before the constructor call ListofAudioFiles, without changing completely my program structure?

Comment: That's probably because you're running your long-running-method on the UI thread/ Make sure you use an AsyncTask or another way of pushing your operation to a worker thread.

Comment: You might find this useful: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0Z5MZ0jL2BM&list=PLWz5rJ2EKKc9CBxr3BVjPTPoDPLdPIFCE&index=2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't change the view to something like a waiting screen because you are running the constructor on the *UI Thread*.

You might have guessed it already, everything UI-related is done on the UI thread, including making a view disappear, changing text etc. When you call the time-consuming constructor, the constructor is actually executed on the UI Thread. This means that the UI thread is busy loading your audio files (which it isn't supposed to do). How can it possibly update the UI (which it is supposed to do)?

As a result, the UI Thread stops updating the UI until the time-consuming operation to finish. To the user, this looks like that the app has frozen.

So what can you do? You can either create an `AsyncTask` subclass, or a new `Thread` object. The former is recommended.

The `onPostExecute` method in `AsyncTask` will be called when it finish loading the audio files. You just need to override that method to know when the operation has finished!

You can learn more about `AsyncTask` here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html